# epoch with milliseconds to timestamp with milliseconds conversion in Hive

Tags: hive, timestamp, hiveql, unix-timestamp

How can I convert unix epoch with milliseconds to timestamp with milliseconds In Hive?
Neither cast() nor from_unixtime() function is working to get the timestamp with milliseconds.

I tried `.SSS` but the function just increases the year and doesn't take it as a part of millisecond.

```
scala> spark.sql("select from_unixtime(1598632101000, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS')").show(false)
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|from_unixtime(1598632101000, yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS)|
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|52628-08-20 02:00:00.000                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can just `cast()`:

```
select cast(1598632101000 / 1000.0 as timestamp)
```

Note that this produces a `timestamp` datatype rather than a string, as in `from_unixtime()`.

Comment: thanks @GMB ! I tried this before as well but as it trimmed the milliseconds(in this particular case where epoch has `000` at last), made me think whether it works in all cases or not.

Answer (score 2):

`from_unixtime` works with seconds, not milliseconds. Convert to timestamp in seconds from_unixtime(ts div 1000), concatenate with '.'+ milliseconds (mod(ts,1000)) and cast as timestamp. Tested in Hive:

```
with your_data as (
select stack(2,1598632101123, 1598632101000) as ts
)

select cast(concat(from_unixtime(ts div 1000),'.',mod(ts,1000)) as timestamp)
from your_data;
```

Result:

```
2020-08-28 16:28:21.123
2020-08-28 16:28:21.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way in pure Spark Scala using UDF to wrap the Java function to return `new Timestamp(ms)`

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
val fromMilli = udf((ms:Long) => new Timestamp(ms))

#Test
val df = Seq((1598632101123L)).toDF("ts")
df.select(fromMilli($"ts")).show(false)
```

Result

```
+-----------------------+
|UDF(ts)                |
+-----------------------+
|2020-08-28 16:28:21.123|
+-----------------------+
```