# What version of Hive do I need to have timestamps with more than 6 decimal places in the fractional seconds?

Tags: hive, timestamp, hiveql

What version of Hive do I need to use this:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/CAST...FORMAT+with+SQL%3A2016+datetime+formats

It lists a way to cast strings as timestamps given a specified format, but it doesn't seem to work, and the related Jira story to this feature doesn't seem to have ever been released. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-21575

Does anyone know?

Comment: Hive supports nanosecond precision timestamp and you can convert using other methods, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jira HIVE-21575](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-21575) is about introducing a way to use SQL:2016 compatible format instead of currently used [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and at the same time it should provide simple method for conversion non-standard timestamp formats with precision.
And I have found that child [Jira HIVE-21868](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-21868) released in version 4.0

What you can do if you have Hive < 4.0:

1. Standard timestamp format is 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS' (up to 9 digits precision). If you have strings in this format, you can convert to timestamp using `timestamp(str)` or `cast(str as timestamp)`, though in most cases you do not need explicit conversion, it will be done implicitly, precision is not lost, you can insert such strings into timestamp column and compare with timestamps without conversion.
2. For timestamps in non standard format with nanoseconds you need conversion.
   The problem here is that `date_format` method does not work because it expects timestamp in standard format. `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(str, format))` does not work because `unix_timestamp` function returns seconds, not nanoseconds, after this conversion, milliseconds and nanoseconds will be lost.

The solution for non-standard formats is to extract milliseconds or nanoseconds  from string, apply conversion in seconds using unix_timestamp(str, format), concatenate result with milliseconds, then convert to timestamp using timestamp() or cast (this last step is not necessary).

Demo (Hive 2.3.6):

```
with your_data as (
select
'16AUG2001:23:46:32.123456789'  --non standard format
 as ts
) 

select ts as original_string, 
       timestamp( --in most cases you can do without final timestamp() conversion
       concat(
              from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(split(ts,'\\.')[0],'ddMMMyyyy:HH:mm:ss')), --timestamp with seconds precision
              '.', split(ts,'\\.')[1] --digits after dot
             ) 
                ) as timestamp_converted
  from your_data;
```

Result:

```
original_string                 timestamp_converted
16AUG2001:23:46:32.123456789    2001-08-16 23:46:32.123456789
```

As you can see, it works fine with nanoseconds precision. I am using final timestamp(string) conversion just to show that string produced is compatible with timestamp, you can omit explicit conversion timestamp(string).

3. If you initially have bigint unix timestamp in milliseconds and want to convert it to Hive timestamp, see this recipe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63672215/2700344
4. A bit different method if you have strings like this "2019-11-02T20:18:00.123Z", see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58713989/2700344
   This method works if string can be easily converted to standard format using regexp_replace.

Comment: What version of Hive are you using? I am using 2.3.3 and don't seem to be able to have more than 6 digits of precision in the fractional seconds, certainly not up to 9 (that would be nice!)

Comment: @emberfly I'm using 2.3.6

Comment: @emberfly This `timestamp('2001-08-16 23:46:32.123456789') ` - also does not work? then it is wrong Hive version

Comment: @emberfly Read also this: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/HIVE-datatype-Timestamp-with-miliseconds/td-p/150944   Hive 2.3.2 works fine with 9 digits

Comment: @emberfly What client are you using? maybe it is client problem. I tested in Hue and Qubole GUI